# How do I compare two hashes containing ~25000 hashes?

Tags: ruby, hash, compare

I have two hashes containing multiple hashes (product information).

What I want to do is compare the two hashes and see what products got added, deleted, updated (e.g. price, description, image).

```
old_hash.size
# => 24595

new_hash.size
# => 26153
```

Here's what structure of the two hashes look like:

```
{"wi230075"=>
  {"itemId"=>"wi230075",
   "description"=>"AH Verse frietaardappelen",
   "salesUnitSize"=>"2,5 kg",
   "images"=>[...]
   "fromPrice"=>2.19,
   "basePrice"=>{"price"=>2.19, "unitPriceDescription"=>"0.96/KG"},
   "score"=>0,
   "frozen"=>false,
   "isPBO"=>false,
   "outOfStock"=>false,
   "quantity"=>0,
   "extendedAttributes"=>[],
   "sourceId"=>{"source"=>"wi", "id"=>230075, "asString"=>"wi230075"},
   "hqIdSource"=>"AH_HQ",
   "hqId"=>822729,
   "productId"=>230075,
   "links"=>[],
   "category"=>"/Aardappel, groente, fruit/Aardappelen/Hele aardappel/",
   "brand"=>"AH"},
  {...}
}
```

I've tried comparing the two hashes using the [HashDiff gem](https://github.com/liufengyun/hashdiff). Here's what I get:

```
diff = HashDiff.diff(old_hash, new_hash)
diff.size
# => 64378
```

Something seems to be going wrong, there can't be 64378 changes.

What is a better way to compare the two hashes?

**Edit:**

I'd just like to know if a product got added, deleted or edited. If it did, a simple `true` would suffice.

Comment: That gem is not going to know which internal hashes to compare against which is why everything seems different in the output you get.

Comment: Why do you think there can’t be `64378` differencies? One new top level element will produce `N` patches, where `N` is an amount of subkeys. Take a look at documentation closely.

Comment: This should probably be done using a database. They're really good at this sort of problem.

Comment: @mudasobwa because ~1% of the products change **slightly**, just the price or description for example.

Comment: @narzero You must be kidding. You have `26153 - 24595 ≈ 1500` brand new records.

Comment: @mudasobwa not counting brand new records, obviously. I'm talking about changes in product data for existing products, not new ones or ones that get deleted.

Comment: @narzero 1500 brand new records produce `N×1500` diffs. This easily gives 64K. If you need to examine the differences in existing products only, you should run `HashDiff` on `new_hash` intersected with `old_hash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return all the keys that were changed (i.e. created, removed or updated):

```
(old_hash.keys | new_hash.keys).select { |k| old_hash[k] != new_hash[k] }
```

To get specific you can do something like:

```
keys = (old_hash.keys | new_hash.keys)
new_keys = keys.select { |k| old_hash[k].nil? }
deleted_keys = keys.select { |k| new_hash[k].nil? }
modified_keys = keys.select { |k| old_hash[k] != new_hash[k] }
unchanged_keys = keys - (new_keys | deleted_keys | modified_keys)
```

This assumes you're not interested in keys with nil values. If you are then you should obviously replace the .nil? call with something else.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't test the code, but i think it looks like this

To get the added record:

```
added_keys = new_hash.keys - old_hash.keys
added_records = new_hash.select{|k,v| added_keys.include? k}
```

To get the removed record:

```
removed_keys = old_hash.keys - new_hash.keys
removed_records = old_hash.select{|k,v| removed_keys.include? k}
```

To get the changed record:

```
changed_records = new_hash.select do |k,v|
  old_hash.has_key?(k) && (old_hash[k]["description"] != new_hash[k]["description"] || old_hash[k]["images"] != new_hash[k]["images"] || old_hash[k]["basePrice"] != new_hash[k]["basePrice"] )
end
```